# Single chip level shifter from LVCMOS to 12 V

Tags: level-shifting, logic-level, level-translation

I'm working on a nixie clock based on a [STM32L476RG](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l476rg.pdf) microcontroller and [HV5530](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005851A.pdf) chips. The microcontroller uses 3.3 V logic while the HV5530 really needs 12 V logic, which is a pain to implement. There are buffer ICs that raise the level from 3.3 V to 5 V, but I was unable to find any that works with 12 V. I experimented with a circuit based on the LM339 with a reference voltage of 0.6 V generated with a forward biased diode and pullup resistors to 12 V. It works, but I prefer to use a single chip. I've spent hours online trying to find a chip that does this, but none comply with 12 V output. I looked for both open drain outputs or push pull outputs without success.

Is there a single chip that does 4 channel, one way shifting from 3.3 V to 12 V?

Comment: What speed do you need?

Comment: Just one example: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7406.pdf

Comment: Not single chip BUT can be VERY compact. 4 NPN transistors. Each collector via R to 12V. Inputs to emitters. Bases to 3V3 via an R - MAY be able to combine all 4 bases and use a single R for bases. Total 4 x NPN (array or tiny pkgs), 4 x pullup Rs to 12V if destinations do not self pullup. One or 4 base Rs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a 74HCT input (1.5V threshold) with CD4000B outputs which do not exist.

But fortunately CD4000B's have level-shifters that work from 3 to 15V.  or even 18 to 20V

One of them is the CD40109B .

Comment: I came across the CD40109B, but I think my conditions are outside the recommended operating boundary specified in the datasheet. The chip doesn't even have specs for 3.3 V. Do you think it is safe to use in my circuit?

Comment: But you didn't specify load capacitance and rise time so beware CD4000 is about RdsOn= 2k to 3k at 3V  and then 300 Ohms at  vs 3.6V logic is 25 Ohms

Comment: Update: I tested the CD40109B and it works in my circuit.

Comment: atta boy Stelian